# Advertise custom terminal size while running expect from a php webpage

Tags: php, tcl, telnet, expect

I am using php to execute an expect script which telnets to a remote server. 
The problem is
I am encountering a lot of 'more' prompts from the server that usually occurs when the screen is full. 
Is there a way to fool the server by advertising my screen size to be large?

Please note that I am not running php from cli, hence not sure how stty can be used here.

Comment: What terminal is expect pretending to be to remote system? What is the TERM environment variable it sets?

Comment: Currently I'm setting it to xterm. But that's not mandatory for me.

Comment: what are you logging in to? if you're telnetting into a cisco device you can disable the pager with `term length 0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recently I had the same need. After a lot of googling, reading a sources of telnet and expect manual page I have found a solution. You can set your desired pseudo-terminal (pty) size to 10000x200 for example like this:

```
set stty_init "rows 10000 cols 200"
spawn -nottycopy telnet 192.168.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

The telnet server works out the window size using [RFC 1073](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1073.html), the Telnet window size option. It's often called NAWS, which stands for **N**egotiate **A**bout **W**indow **S**ize. What telnet client are you using, and are you able to override the NAWS message it sends?